# Recursive CTE to get a Category and all its ancestors

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression

I have been fiddling with [this Recursive CTE Example](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) to see if I can get the hierarchy from ground up.

In my scenario I have a Category table like following

CategoryID
CategoryName
ParentCategoryID

I have the following Recursive CTE Query

```
;WITH CategoriesCTE AS
( 
 SELECT c.CategoryID, c.CategoryName, c.ParentCategoryID
 FROM Category c
 WHERE c.ParentCategoryID IS NOT NULL

 UNION ALL

 SELECT c.CategoryID, c.CategoryName, c.ParentCategoryID
 FROM Category c
 INNER JOIN CategoriesCTE p
 ON p.CategoryID=c.ParentCategoryID
 WHERE c.ParentCategoryID IS NULL
 )

 -- Get the category with the ID 13 and all its ancestors
 SELECT * FROM CategoriesCTE
 WHERE CategoryID = 13
```

The above query is not returning me results, I am sure it is because my where clause is limiting it. How do I fix it?

Comment: Replace firts where for the last one. (Delete first one and move last one to first sql sentence)

Comment: Neither select in the CTE are showing FROM clauses and tables...Also imo a bit quick to close this.  The question indicates they are trying to learn how to do this and have studied examples and now is asking for specific help with a specific issue; not a general "how do I build a recursive cte..."  specific questions IMO deserve specific answers.

Comment: Did that fix the problem are you now getting results?